# Erro: CURL can't connect: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php

Estou utilizando a API do pagseguro para efetuar compras no meu site, ele estava funcionando muito bem, normalmente. Hoje quando fui usar novamente começou a apresentar esse erro:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/usuario/
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'CURL can't connect: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl' in /home/onecom/public_html/admin/PagSeguroLibrary/utils/PagSeguroHttpConnection.class.php:120Stack trace: was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

O meu Token e email configurado estão corretos, mas não sei o que pode ser. O código que estou usando:

```
<?php 

require_once "../PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php";

class CreatePaymentRequest
{

    public static function main()
    {

        $paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();

        $paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");

        $paymentRequest->addItem('0001', 'notebook', 2, 430.00);

        $paymentRequest->addItem('0002', 'notebook 2', 2, 560.00);


        $paymentRequest->setReference("REF123");

        $paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("http://www.lojamodelo.com.br");


        try {

            $credentials = new PagSeguroAccountCredentials("alisson@habeo.com.br","MEU-TOKEN");

            $url = $paymentRequest->register($credentials);

            self::printPaymentUrl($url);
        } catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function printPaymentUrl($url)
    {
        if ($url) {
            echo "<h2>Criando requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o de pagamento</h2>";
            echo "<p>URL do pagamento: <strong>$url</strong></p>";
            echo "<p><a title=\"URL do pagamento\" href=\"$url\">Ir para URL do pagamento.</a></p>";
        }
    }
}

CreatePaymentRequest::main();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz que o protocolo HTTPS não é suportado ou está desabilitado na biblioteca cURL do seu servidor. Tem que ter essa biblioteca instalada e ativa.

Se mesmo assim não funcionar você deve verificar com a sua empresa de hospedagem se é possível habilitar ou então mudar de host, pois o PagSeguro só trabalha com URLs seguras (https).

Comment: Pelo phpinfo() da para mim verificar se está habilitado o https? Pois no localhost eu coloquei um phpinfo() e em `Registered PHP Streams` apareceu o HTTPS. Agora no servidor web não aparece

Comment: Procure no PHP info no seu servidor algo sobre "cURl support” se vc achar é por que está instalado.

Comment: basta acessar o seu arquivo php.ini que geralmente fica dentro da pasta php do seu servidor (sim, você precisa ter acesso a esse arquivo) e procure por essa linha:

;extension=php_curl.dll

Agora remova o ponto-e-vírgula (;) do começo da linha, reinicie o seu servidor e verifique se está ok.